# Error "Types of property ''data-tooltip-content'' are incompatible." when using react-tooltip

Tags: reactjs, react-tooltip

I have this code:

```
<button
      type="button"
      data-tooltip-id="columns-setings-tooltip"
      className={clsx(
        styles.rowControlPanelColumnsOptions,
        isColumnsDialogVisible && styles.highlight
      )}
      data-tooltip-content={t(`${translationBase}.columnsSettings`)}
      onClick={handleColumnsControlPanel}
    >
      <Tooltip id="columns-setings-tooltip" />

      <ColumnsIcon />
    </button>
```

And I get TS error in the `button` tag (no matter if I use `div` or something else btw) that  `Types of property ''data-tooltip-content'' are incompatible.` which is something I didn't get in the past with this library. Someone has an idea where this types incompatibility comes from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade the package to the latest version `react-tooltip@latest`. Since v5.17.0, this shouldn't be an issue anymore. If you're unable to upgrade for any reason, see below.

---

`data-tooltip-content` (before v5.17.0) expects `string | undefined`. The return type for `t()` (`DefaultTFuncReturn`) is not compatible, so you must pass it like so:

```
data-tooltip-content={t(`${translationBase}.columnsSettings`) ?? ''}
```

You could also use `||` instead of `??` but I suggest keeping it like that.

Comment: Thank you @Gabriel! Yes, this was the issue, I figured it out shortly before your answer :) I just wrapper the translation function in a String constructor.